# Why onCreate called multiple time?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When i created class extends Activity, and all activity extends the class, onCreate calls multiple time.

ex) there is custom class 'BaseActivity'

```
public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity {
    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and create some class extends 'BaseActivity'

```
public class AnotherActivity : BaseActivity {
    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

this case, AnotherActivity's onCreate called two times. if i create AnotherActivity2 and these classes Navigated sequencially, then AnotherActivity2's onCreate called three times. Why are these happening?

Comment: Suppose you have three activities A, B, C all extends BaseActivity. Your flow is like A to B, B to C. Right ?

Comment: Right. if I go A to B, B's onCreated called two times, and go B to C, C's onCreated called three times.

Comment: This is extremely old but did you ever get an answer for this?